# Mongodb sorting by nested array object of type "ISO Date" that is not defined

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, nosql

For the document schema below, we found a way of sorting based on an array where each item has an object with dueDate and completed.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5644c474bfe77aab75c1093a"),
"tasks" : [
    {
        "completed" : false,
        "dueDate" : /(?:)/,
    },
    {
        "dueDate" : ISODate("2015-11-15T05:00:00Z"),
        "completed" : true,
    },
    {
        "dueDate" : ISODate("2013-01-01T05:00:00Z"),
        "completed" : true,
    },
    {
        "dueDate" : ISODate("2012-01-01T05:00:00Z"),
        "completed" : true,
    }
]
}
```

Here's the sorting function we're using.

```
.sort({ "tasks.completed": -1, "tasks.dueDate": 1 })
```

There are tasks that don't have dueDate and in order for sort to work, it requires us to initialize dueDate with `new RegExp()` in order for sort to down sort it or have it not appear in our lists of results.